# Jdbc Odbc Driver supporting in android

Tags: android

Android Supports JDBC ODBC Driver for accessing MDB database. If yes then how access MDB database from android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will want to build some kind of middleware application (i.e. RESTful web app, etc) to interface between your Android clients, and your backend database.

I suppose you *could* include a whole bunch of ODBC libraries on Android, but that seems absolutely the wrong way to be doing things.

Answer (score 0):

android,iphone all phones supports light weight DB.

thats y all the phone require the `SQLIte Database`.

because all the phone application running in light weight process.

So according to me JDBC ODBC will not accessing in mobile phone.

http://www.patrickmcdaniel.org/pubs/ccs09a.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But In my project I have one requirement in that I have to connect to the MDB database and from mdb database I have to take data and Inserted into SQlite database. I am facing problem while connecting to the MDB database. It is very urgent requirement in my project.